# Why does my Docker container fail on executing a simple Python script?

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, docker, flask

I'm trying to [Dockerize a Flask](http://containertutorials.com/docker-compose/flask-simple-app.html) app, but the container exits immediately after run. Further inspection reveals a Python syntax error as the culprit.

Edit: the tutorial has errors in its code samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown us the contents of `app.py` (which you should have), but the error message says that Python is failing on the line `From flask import Flask`.  Assuming that's actually what your code looks like, the problem is the `From`; it's supposed to be `from`, with a lowercase F.

Comment: I'm copying the exact contents from the tutorial I linked in. I totally overlooked this, my Python was a little rusty. Thanks.